# Signing google cloud storage url in R

Tags: r, google-cloud-storage

I would like to sign a URL to allow a user to download a file from a google bucket.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

We would like to add this capability to https://github.com/cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR. Putting together a string to sign is fairly straightforward, but the actual signature in R remains a mystery to me. There are number of examples for other languages, but they seem to rely on purpose-built functionality that is not available in R (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Doesn't this explain it? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an R library that can calculate an RSA sha256? I believe there's an openssl package that might do the trick.